# Using nested select properly in a sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a query to aggregate clicks from a db

contains an entry with a time and date for every click

I am stuck though since my query don't "compile" 

I want to aggregate the clicks in between certain hours and display them in a catagory 

(morning, noon, evening, night) How can I do that? - here is what I do as for now

```
SELECT n
FROM click_history
Where (SELECT count(*) from click_history where click_history_hour BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '12:00:00') as n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to aggregate by hour, then I would expect to see a `group by`.  Maybe something like this:

```
select (case when click_history_hour < '08:00:00' then 'time1'
             when click_history_hour < '12:00:00' then 'time2'
             else 'time3'
        end) as whichtime, count(*) as n
from click_history
group by (case when click_history_hour < '08:00:00' then 'time1'
               when click_history_hour < '12:00:00' then 'time2'
               else 'time3'
        end);
```

Of course, the names of the periods and there definition is up to you.